# How to define a two dimensional array in Python using Array Module?

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

How to define a two dimensional array in Python using **Array Module**? I know how to do it using different module like numpy or lists. I am interested particularly in Array Module. 
I tried to create like this, it gives error of "TypeError: an integer is required (got type list)"

```
from array import *

twoDArray = array('i', [[11, 12, 5, 2],[15, 6,10, 0]] )
```

Comment: Based on the docs & people's comments on some other forums, array module doesn't support multi dimensions.

Answer (score -1):

I suppose we cannot use `array` module to store values of other than int , Unicode character and float .

> Arrays are sequence types and behave very much like lists, except that the type of objects stored in them is constrained. The type is specified at object creation time by using a type code, which is a single character

[Refer this site](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html#module-array)